# How to column bind 2 tables but remove the same column

Tags: r, bind

i want to join 2 Table with same column but only 1 different column and display the same column to one single column.

if:

dt1 <- have the column names (a,b,c,d,e)

a  b  c  d  e

1  2  3  4  5

1  2  3  4  5

1  2  3  4  5

dt2 <- have the column names (a,b,c,d,f)

a  b  c  d  f

1  2  3  4  6

1  2  3  4  6

1  2  3  4  6

```
dt3 <- cbind(dt1, dt2)
```

*I just want to do some simple table combining with R using cbind*

**This yield:**

dt3 <- have the column names(a,b,c,d,e,a,b,c,d,f)

a  b  c  d  e  a  b  c  d  f

1  2  3  4  5  1  2  3  4  6

1  2  3  4  5  1  2  3  4  6

1  2  3  4  5  1  2  3  4  6

**i want the output to be:**

dt3 <- have the column names (a,b,c,d,e,f)

a  b  c  d  e  f

1  2  3  4  5  6

1  2  3  4  5  6

1  2  3  4  5  6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `setdiff` to get the columns in one that is not found in another

```
nm1 <- setdiff(names(dt2), names(dt1))
out <- cbind(dt1, dt2[nm1])
```

---

If we have multiple datasets, place it in a `list` get the `intersect`ing column names (names that are common in all), get the `setdiff` of those from the column names of each individual datasets in the `list` and `cbind`

```
lst1 <- list(dt1, dt2, dt3)
nm2 <- Reduce(intersect, lapply(lst1, names))
cbind(lst1[[1]], do.call(cbind,
    lapply(lst1[-1], function(dat) dat[setdiff(names(dat), nm2)] )))
#    a  b  c  d  e  f  g
#1   1 11 21 31 41 51 61
#2   2 12 22 32 42 52 62
#3   3 13 23 33 43 53 63
#4   4 14 24 34 44 54 64
#5   5 15 25 35 45 55 65
#6   6 16 26 36 46 56 66
#7   7 17 27 37 47 57 67
#8   8 18 28 38 48 58 68
#9   9 19 29 39 49 59 69
#10 10 20 30 40 50 60 70
```

---

Or using a `for` loop

```
out1 <- dt1 # initialize with the first data
for(i in 2:length(lst1)) {

    out1 <- cbind(out1, lst1[[i]][setdiff(names(lst1[[i]]), nm2)])
}
out1
```

#### data

```
dt1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:50, 10, 5, dimnames = list(NULL, letters[1:5])))
dt2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(11:60, 10, 5, dimnames = list(NULL, letters[c(1:4, 6)])))
dt3 <-  as.data.frame(matrix(21:70, 10, 5, 
     dimnames = list(NULL, letters[c(1:4, 7)])))
```

Comment: can the setdiff(x...,y...) function used for many variable? such as dt1,dt2,dt3,dt4? setdiff(names(dt1),names(dt2),names(dt3),names(dt4)

Comment: @Srome  You can place it in a list and use `Reduce(setdiff, list(names(dt2), names(dt1)))`

Comment: Sorry, but im not really good in this thing as im still a beginner, so i can't really write what do i want in this question but your answer is perfect. Now i just need to make this work if i have more than 2 variable (the dt) to combine. Does a for loop in r works just like in python or it works differently?

Comment: @Srome I updated the answer.  It sshould work for you

Comment: yes, i just seen it, thanks a lot for helping me dude.

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner:

```
library(dplyr)
dt1 %>%
    bind_cols(select(dt2, -one_of(names(.))))
```

---

This will work with more datasets, i.e. you can add another line with a dt3 below.

**Big, bad BUT**: What you are trying to do will not necessarily make sense in every context. What if the number of rows is different across the datasets? What if columns that have the same name contain different data? What about different data types? ...

> I just want to do some simple table combining with R using cbind

If you're trying to do something in a language that apparently *Was Made to Do Things Like That, But Doesn't* it sometimes makes sense to take a step back and question your approach. **Why** are you trying to select those columns? **What** is the goal? **Which** are the requirements? **Where** does this data come from? **Where** will it go to? I would suspect that in this case there are better ways to accomplish what you are trying to do than to try to find differently-named columns.

If you elaborate a bit on that I'll be happy to suggest a more robust approach to reach your goal!

---

#### Data

```
dt1 <- data.frame(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5)
dt2 <- data.frame(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, f = 6)
```